# Intel NUC no sound over hdmi terminal commands

Tags: sound

I have just installed ubuntu on my intel nuc. I am trying to fix the fact I have no sound over hdmi. I found the supposed fix in the following instructions:

**No audio through HDMI (many flavors of Ubuntu): This isn't specific to the NUC as it seems to be happening on lots of builds, but it's easy to get around:
Make sure your system is up to date using the Update Manager
Add the following groups to your account: audio, pulse, pulse-access, video, voice
In a terminal window run the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-audio-dev/alsa-daily
apt update
apt install oem-audio-hda-daily-dkms
```

Reboot the system**

The problem is when I get as far as running "apt update" terminal doesnt recongnise the command. Has anyone any idea where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the error, `apt` just isn't a command. You need `apt-get` and you'll need to prepend that with `sudo` to run them as root. So the last two commands should read:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oem-audio-hda-daily-dkms
```

Comment: After successfully updating and it still doesn't work, post your NUC model and flavor and version of linux you are trying to use in your OP.

Comment: Thank you so much! So simple. Sound is working now over hdmi. I'm just getting the hang of doing  commands as I'm new to linux, so thank you for your patience!!!!